# Travis builds twice every commit (two tasks per build)

Tags: java, travis-ci

Example build: https://travis-ci.org/sscarduzio/elasticsearch-readonlyrest-plugin/builds/322220103

Notice how there is 1 build per commit and **2 identical, parallel tasks for each build.** Which is an issue because each build takes forever!

My `.travis.yml` configuration:

```
sudo: required
dist: trusty
group: deprecated-2017Q4

language: java

sudo: required

services:
  - docker

jdk:
- oraclejdk8

branches:
  except:
    - /^v[0-9].*es/

script: bin/build.sh

deploy:
  provider: script
  script: ci/ci-deploy.sh
  skip_cleanup: true
  on:
    all_branches: true
    tags: false

env:
- GH_USER_EMAIL=scarduzio+travisci@gmail.com
- GH_USER_NAME=Travis CI

before_script:
  - sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144

after_success:
- |

       declare -r SSH_FILE="$HOME/.ssh/gh_identity)"

       # - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

       # Decrypt the file containing the private key

       openssl aes-256-cbc \
         -K $encrypted_bf4db9d5783b_key -iv $encrypted_bf4db9d5783b_iv \
         -in ".travis/github_deploy_key.enc" \
         -out "$SSH_FILE" -d

       # - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

       # Enable SSH authentication

       chmod 600 "$SSH_FILE" \
         && printf "%s\n" \
              "Host github.com" \
              "  IdentityFile $SSH_FILE" \
              "  LogLevel ERROR" >> ~/.ssh/config
```

```

Comment: can you try leaving only one of the `env` parameters instead of both `GH_USER_EMAIL` and `GH_USER_NAME`? I think that causes your build running twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is being caused by the `env` configuration. Travis sees this as a [build matrix](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#Build-Matrix). I believe the correct way is to use the global key:

```
env:
  global:
    - GH_USER_EMAIL=
    - GH_USER_NAME=
```